# How to query NaN double values in Athena

Tags: sql, parquet, amazon-athena, presto

I need to query something like in AWS Athena

```
SELECT * FROM "hl"."may" where fqk = 'NaN' limit 10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`is_nan`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/math.html#is_nan):

```
select is_nan(nan());

 _col0
-------
 true
```

Answer (score 2):

I was about to suggest is_nan... but it didnt work for me either as I tought it was specific to Python or Spark...
However this worked for me.

SELECT * FROM "hl"."may" where cast(fqk as VARCHAR(4))  = 'NaN' limit 10

Comment: Can you elaborate what didn't work with `is_nan` for you? Maybe your value wasn't a double?

Comment: Athena wasnt recognizing it... I got this error : Your query has the following error(s):

Conversion = ''' (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 7014cdc5-ab9b-46e2-938d-32c2de1df629)... But I know it works in other languages, I do use is_nan but in python...

Comment: Athena will not let me detect NaN. I have tried is_nan() and CAST(col as varchar). Nothing works.